# How to find the patient with at least three HbA1c values more than 6.5 using R

Tags: r

I have a dataset contains patient ID and HbA1c.

```
df <- data.frame(PATIENT_ID=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                     HbA1c=c(6.4,6.5,6.7,6.5,6.7,6.1,6.9,6.7,7.0,6.4))
```

I want to find the patients who had at least three HbA1c values more than 6.5. The output should be a dataset of unique patient ID and the first HbA1c value more than 6.5. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping by 'PATIENT_ID', we can `filter` those having 3 or more HbA1c values greater than or equal to 6.5 and get the `distinct` 'PATIENT_ID'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
      group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>%
      filter(sum(HbA1c >= 6.5) >=3 & HbA1c >= 6.5) %>%
      distinct(PATIENT_ID, .keep_all = TRUE)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
# Groups:   PATIENT_ID [1]
#  PATIENT_ID HbA1c
#      <dbl> <dbl>
#1          1   6.5
```

---

Or with `slice`

```
df %>%
 filter(HbA1c >= 6.5) %>%
    group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>% 
    filter(n() >=3) %>%
    slice(1)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
# Groups:   PATIENT_ID [1]
#  PATIENT_ID HbA1c
#       <dbl> <dbl>
#1          1   6.5
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[HbA1c >= 6.5, .SD[.N >=3], PATIENT_ID][1]
#   PATIENT_ID HbA1c
#1:          1   6.5
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
i1 <- rowsum(+(df$HbA1c >= 6.5), df$PATIENT_ID) >=3
subset(df, PATIENT_ID %in% names(which(i1[,1])) & HbA1c >= 6.5)[1,]
```

---

Or another option is `table` in `base R`

```
names(which(table(df$PATIENT_ID, df$HbA1c >= 6.5)[,2] >=3))
#[1] "1"
```

Or a variant of `table`

```
names(which(table(subset(df, HbA1c >= 6.5)$PATIENT_ID) >=3))
```

Comment: How can I also have the first HbA1c value  >= 6.5 as a row after the patient ID? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we can use `ave` to count number of `HbA1c` values which are more than 6.5 for each `PATIENT_ID`, then use `subset` to select only `PATIENT_ID` column and return `unique` rows.

```
unique(subset(df, ave(HbA1c >= 6.5, PATIENT_ID, FUN = sum) >= 3, 
              select = PATIENT_ID))

#  PATIENT_ID
#1          1
```

We can also use `tapply` :

```
inds <- tapply(df$HbA1c >= 6.5, df$PATIENT_ID, sum) >= 3
names(inds[inds])
#[1] "1"
```

---

To get first `HbA1c` that is greater than 6.5 we can do :

```
df1 <- subset(df, ave(HbA1c >= 6.5, PATIENT_ID, FUN = sum) >= 3)
aggregate(HbA1c~PATIENT_ID, df1, function(x) x[which.max(x >= 6.5)])


#  PATIENT_ID HbA1c
#1          1   6.5
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I also have the first HbA1c value >= 6.5 as a row after the patient ID?

Comment: @NewYorkCrosser Updated the answer.